# Agregar elementos en dos listas al mismo tiempo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo el siguiente código que permite pasar un elemento, en este caso inputs, de un div a otro por un boton o con drag and drop. La idea es que cuando se pase un elemento del div1 al div2, este permanezca en el div1 pero se pase tambien al div2

```js
// PARA EL AGREGADO POR DRAG
        var element = null;
        
        function allowDrop(ev) {
          ev.target.classList.add('feedme');
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
        
        function removeDrop(ev) {
          ev.target.classList.remove('feedme');
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
        
        function drag(ev) {
          element = ev.target;
          element.parentNode.classList.add('feedme');
          element.classList.add('dragging');
        }
        
        function drop(ev) {
          var actionb = element.querySelector('.action-button');
          ev.preventDefault();
          ev.target.classList.remove('feedme');
          element.classList.remove('dragging');
          if (ev.target.classList.contains('droppable')) {
            render(element,ev.target);
          }
          element = null;
        }
// PARA EL AGREGADO POR DRAG
        
// PARA EL AGREGADO POR BOTON        
        // En que renderiza un elemento en un objetivo
        function render(element,target){
          // Calcula el texto que debe mostrar el btn de acción rápida
          element.querySelector('.qaction-button').innerText = (target.id == 'div1') ? '+' : '-';
          // Render!
          target.appendChild(element);
        }
        
        // Fn Accion Rápida, 
        function qaction(){
          // this es el boton que dispara el evento
            var element = this.parentElement;
          // Calculo el objetivo en base al texto del botón de acción
          var targetId = (this.innerText == '+') ? '#div2' : '#div1';
          // Ordeno renderizar el elemento
          render(element,document.querySelector(targetId));
        }
        
        // Ejecutar función acción rápida al realizar click en el boton
        // Buscamos todos los elementos de la clase "acción rápida"
        for (var i in document.querySelectorAll('.qaction-button')){
          // Buenas practicas
            if (isNaN(i)) continue;
          // Añadimos la función qaction para el evento click
            document.querySelectorAll('.qaction-button')[i].addEventListener("click", qaction, false);
        }
// PARA EL AGREGADO POR BOTON
```

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#div1 input,
#div2 input {
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

#div1.feedme,
#div2.feedme {
  background: #FFFFEE;
}

.dragging {
  border: 1px dashed #00F;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="removeDrop(event)">
                  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><button class="qaction-button">+</button><input type="text" value="Debito"></div>
                  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><button class="qaction-button">+</button><input type="text" value="Credito"></div>
                  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><button class="qaction-button">+</button><input type="text" value="Efectivo"></div>
          </div>
                
                
                
                <div id="div2" class="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="removeDrop(event)"></div>
```

Precisamente estaba buscando como usar el cloneNode. Hay forma de tener n debitos, n creditos, etc en el div2?

**Edit1:** @dperezv.com Creo que vi como tener n elementos en el div2 con el codigo que me has facilitado.
Quitando este condicional:
if(target.querySelector('input[value="'+element.querySelector('input').value+'"]')) return true;

El problema es como que como se copia el elemento al arrastrar o pulsar el boton, se van acumulando. 
No veo como modificarle para que solo si agrego al div2 se acumulen los elementos y en el div1 permanezcan los mismos.

Comment: Simplemente debes salir de la función render cada vez que detectes que el contenedor receptor es #div1 con return true. Así dejarás siempre en el estado inicial el primer contenedor. De la misma forma, como bien comentas, comentando la segunda condición consigues añadir tantos elementos como necesites en #div2.

Edito la respuesta para que puedas ver el resultado comentado

Comment: Pero de esa forma si agrego un elemento del div1 al mismo div1 se eliminaria, habia intentado algo similar y lamentablemente con ese mismo resultado.

Comment: ¡O tienes razón! ¡No pensé que puedes 'soltar un elemento' dentro de su propio contenedor!

Vamos a añadir una linea de código para evitar que 'element.parentNode' y 'target' sean el mismo elemento.

Edito la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes una posible solución a tu pregunta!

```js
// PARA EL AGREGADO POR DRAG
        var element = null;
        
        function allowDrop(ev) {
          ev.target.classList.add('feedme');
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
        
        function removeDrop(ev) {
          ev.target.classList.remove('feedme');
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
        
        function drag(ev) {
          element = ev.target;
          element.parentNode.classList.add('feedme');
          element.classList.add('dragging');
        }
        
        function drop(ev) {
          var actionb = element.querySelector('.action-button');
          ev.preventDefault();
          ev.target.classList.remove('feedme');
          element.classList.remove('dragging');
          if (ev.target.classList.contains('droppable')) {
            render(element,ev.target);
          }
          element = null;
        }
// PARA EL AGREGADO POR DRAG
        
// PARA EL AGREGADO POR BOTON        
        // En que renderiza un elemento en un objetivo
        function render(element,target){
        
          // element.parentNode === target ?
          if(element.parentNode.id == target.id) return true;
        
          // Si el objetivo es #div1 :
          // - Eliminamos el elemento
          // - Detenemos la ejecución de la función
          if (target.id == 'div1') { 
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            return true;
          }
          
          // NO Permitir más de un elemento en el contenedor receptor
          //if(target.querySelector('input[value="'+element.querySelector('input').value+'"]')) return true;
          
          // Clonamos el elemento
          var elm = element.cloneNode(true);
          // Acción rápida para el nuevo elemento
          elm.querySelector('.qaction-button').addEventListener("click", qaction, false);
          // Calcula el texto que debe mostrar el btn de acción rápida
          elm.querySelector('.qaction-button').innerText = (target.id == 'div1') ? '+' : '-';
          // Render!
          target.appendChild(elm);
        }
        
        // Fn Accion Rápida, 
        function qaction(){
          // this es el boton que dispara el evento
            var element = this.parentElement;
          // Calculo el objetivo en base al texto del botón de acción
          var targetId = (this.innerText == '+') ? '#div2' : '#div1';
          // Ordeno renderizar el elemento
          render(element,document.querySelector(targetId));
        }
        
        // Ejecutar función acción rápida al realizar click en el boton
        // Buscamos todos los elementos de la clase "acción rápida"
        for (var i in document.querySelectorAll('.qaction-button')){
          // Buenas practicas
            if (isNaN(i)) continue;
          // Añadimos la función qaction para el evento click
            document.querySelectorAll('.qaction-button')[i].addEventListener("click", qaction, false);
        }
// PARA EL AGREGADO POR BOTON
```

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#div1 input,
#div2 input {
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

#div1.feedme,
#div2.feedme {
  background: #FFFFEE;
}

.dragging {
  border: 1px dashed #00F;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="removeDrop(event)">
                  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><button class="qaction-button">+</button><input type="text" value="Debito"></div>
                  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><button class="qaction-button">+</button><input type="text" value="Credito"></div>
                  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><button class="qaction-button">+</button><input type="text" value="Efectivo"></div>
          </div>
                
                
                
                <div id="div2" class="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="removeDrop(event)"></div>
```

Comment: Podrias explicar esta parte del codigo, se que impide que se agreguen mas elementos del div1 al div2, pero no entiendo bien la sintaxis
if(target.querySelector('input[value="'+element.querySelector('input').value+'"]')) return true;

Comment: Siendo 'target' el contenedor donde añadir nuestro elemento y 'element' el elemento que deseamos añadir. Buscamos con querySelector un elemento en 'target' que contenga dentro de su input el valor dado en el elemento 'element' que queremos añadir.

Buscamos crear un selector similar a:
target.querySelector('input[value="Debito"]')

Dónde, si en target existe un input con valor 'Debito' retornará dicho elemento, evaluando la expresión if () ... como positiva, y finalizando la función (return ...) en caso contrario, devolverá null, evaluado como negativo y continuando la ejecución